# Substring using Regex in Shell or bash

Tags: regex, linux, bash, shell

I've a huge text file having row items like following

```
"https://www.wayfair.ca/appliances/pdp/agua-canada-30-500-cfm-ducted-wall-mount-range-hood-agcd1041.html?piid=47570655"
"https://www.wayfair.ca/appliances/pdp/agua-canada-30-500-cfm-ducted-wall-mount-range-hood-agcd1041.html?piid=47570656"
"https://www.wayfair.ca/appliances/pdp/agua-canada-30-500-cfm-ducted-wall-mount-range-hood-agcd1042.html"
"https://www.wayfair.ca/appliances/pdp/agua-canada-30-500-cfm-ducted-wall-mount-range-hood-agcd1043.html?piid=47570657"
"https://www.wayfair.ca/appliances/pdp/agua-canada-30-500-cfm-ducted-wall-mount-range-hood-agcd1043.html?piid=47570658"
```

I want to extract alpha-numeric character after last occurrence of '-' and before '.html' ('agcd1043' only) and save those values to another file.

Kindly help me do this using regex ( .*-(.+).html.* - is the regex I used to npp for smaller files) or any other method. TIA

Comment: Do you need to use regex?  You could just do this with a `cut` pipeline or something.

Comment: @Jason cutting would require to know at which index s/he can cut, which is probably not known in advance

Comment: I mean... this works: `< hugefile.txt rev | cut -d/ -f1 | cut -d. -f2 | cut -d- -f1 | rev`

Comment: @oguzismail there are a few mistakes in your regex: `[^-.]*` you don’t need to exclude the dot character, and `.html` you might prefer `\.html`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could extract the string with `sed`:

```sh
sed 's/.*-\([^-]*\)\.html.*/\1/' <<< "https://www.wayfair.ca/appliances/pdp/agua-canada-30-500-cfm-ducted-wall-mount-range-hood-agcd1041.html?piid=47570655"
```

If you have all your strings in a file you can iterate on it:

```sh
while read line
do
  variable=$(sed 's/.*-\([^-]*\)\.html.*/\1/' <<< $line)
  # ... use the value from $variable
done < /path/to/file
```

The `sed` script is a [substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/html_node/The-_0022s_0022-Command.html), where:

- `.*-\([^-]*\)\.html.*` is the pattern
- `\1` is the replacement

The pattern is written so that it captures any sequence of non-hyphen character, i.e. `[^-]*` trapped between a hypen character `-` and the `.html` string. The dot character is escaped for regex purposes, hence the `\.html` pattern. The leading ad trailing `.*` make sure that anything before the hyphen and after html are captured too, otherwise they would appear in the output.

Comment: It's much more efficient to run `sed` *just once* and have your loop read from its output, rather than running `sed` once per line

Comment: that is to say: `while IFS= read -r line; do ...; done < <(sed ... </path/to/file)` -- if you need a loop at all, and can't just run `sed` against the whole file.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy You are right about the performance but process substitution is a bit overkill for someone who does not know how to use `sed`. I also assume `IFS= read -r` is most probably unnecessary for URLs.

Comment: If we always/unconditionally teach `IFS= read -r line`, then we don't need to teach folks for which data the extra verbosity is and isn't necessary (since folks reading an answer are presumably going to reuse it outside the original problem domain). Making good habits automatic means folks can spend their time thinking about things that actually matter. Similarly, process substitution is only new and surprising to someone who hasn't learned it yet. Teach it, and then someone is no longer in the "hasn't learned it yet" category. :)